# Simple probability exercise.

Tags: statistics

I have this question I need to answer but I'm a bit stuck having done no statistics before.

I don't want any full solutions just hints please.

1. A man can either drive or get the bus to his job. The probability he drives is $0.25$ and the probability he's late when he drives is $0.6$ and $0.4$ if he gets the bus.

I) What is the probability he is late on any day?

II) If he is late what is the probability he caught the bus?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L$ be the event that the man is late. So you're after $P(L)$. There's two ways he can be late: by car or by bus, both mutually exclusive events. So let $C$ be the even that he took a car and $B$ the event that he took a bus. Clearly $C^c=B$ by mutual exclusivity. So $P(L)=P(L|C)P(C)+P(L|B)P(B)$ by the the law of conditional expectation. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: Yes thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The Probability he drove and is late = 0.25 * 0.6 = 0.15.
The Probability he takes the bus and is late = 0.75 * 0.4 = 0.30

So the probability he is late is the sum of these two, or 0.45.

The probability given that he is late that he caught a bus is 0.30/0.45 = 2/3.

Answer (score 0):

For any particular day, there are four possible combinations of events.
Drove and was Late
Drove and was Not Late
Bus and was Late
Bus and was Not Late

These events are mutually exclusive and you can assign probabilities to each possible event based on the clues in the problem statement. If done correctly, these should sum to $1$, because these are ALL combinations.

Note that the likelihood of him driving and being late $P($Drives and  Late$)$ can be broken into two steps, the probability that he was late given that he drove, and the probability that he drives. $P($Drives and Late$) = P($Late because he drove$)P($He Drives$)$

Further, he cannot take both the bus as well as drive, so these events are mutually exclusive and don't offer any further possible modes of transportation. Because of this
$P($He Drives$) = 1 - P($He takes Bus$)$